# Stored Procedure not listed when adding in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures

I have a db with 2 schema, dbo and Form.  In dbo I created a stored proc.  I am working on an ASP MVC app.  I went into VS2010, into the edmx file representing the dbo schema and tried 'Update Model From DB", to get the SP into the app, but it is not listed.

I am thinking it is a security issue (the entity connection uses a username and password) but I a not sure what permissions I need to grant, but I could be totally wrong.

Any ideas on how to remedy this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must grant execute permissions to the user as whom VS is connecting. I often forget to do this and get the same problem.